# Using factory_girl_rails with Rspec on namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, rspec, factory-bot

I have a web service that serves Ads to several different clients. The structure of the Ad varies between clients, and therefore, I am using namespaces for my models and controllers by the client name to differentiate between Ads. From the high level, it looks like this:

`'app/models/client1/ad.rb'`

```
class Client1::Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description
end
```

`'app/models/client2/ad.rb'`

```
class Client2::Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :source
end
```

In reality, these models are more complex and have associations, but that is not the point.
I am writing some unit tests using rspec-rails 2.4.0 and factory_girl_rails 1.0.1, and all of my factories work great. However, I am not able to define factories for the namespaced models. I've tried something like:

```
Factory.define :client1_ad, :class => Client1::Ad do |ad|
  ad.title       "software tester"  
  ad.description "Immediate opening"
end
```

and

```
Factory.define :client2_ad, :class => Client2::Ad do |ad|
  ad.title       "software tester"  
  ad.description "Immediate opening"
  ad.source      "feed"
end
```

It didn't do the job. I looked around, but every single example that I saw was using non-namespaced models. Anyone have any ideas? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have a minimal working example here, maybe you could use it to pinpoint where your problem is. The comment you left on dmarkow's answer suggests to me that you have an error someplace else.

*app/models/bar/foo.rb*

```
class Bar::Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

*db/migrate/20110614204536_foo.rb*

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :foos
  end
end
```

*spec/factories.rb*

```
Factory.define :foo, :class => Bar::Foo do |f|
  f.name 'Foooo'
end
```

*spec/models/foo_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Bar::Foo do

  it 'does foo' do
    foo = Factory(:foo)
    foo.name.should == 'Foooo'
  end
end
```

Running the test:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:test:prepare
$ rspec  spec/models/foo_spec.rb 
.

Finished in 0.00977 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer, Jorge. Seems like my problem was that I did not run `rake db:test:prepare`. Accepted, voted up.

Comment: I'm curious, shouldn't your tablename be `bar_foos` instead of `foos`?

Answer (score 12):

I think maybe FactoryGirl changes since this answer was posted. I did to make it work

```
Factory.define do
  factory :foo, :class => Bar::Foo do |f|
    f.name 'Foooo'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

With the current latest version of `FactoryGirl` (**4.5.0**), this is the syntax:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client1_ad, class: Client1::Ad do |f|
    f.title       "software tester"
    f.description "Immediate opening"
  end
end
```

Notice that `client1_ad` can be whatever name you want coz we already force identifying its ***class name***.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question looking into a related issue with FactoryGirl and after a little reading of the source I figured out I could solve my problem by renaming my factories.

When I had model classes that were namespaced inside modules, eg: `Admin::User` I should have been defining my factories like this:

```
factory :'admin/user', class: Admin::User do
  #...
end
```

Rather than:

```
factory :admin_user, class: Admin::User do
  #...
end
```

Maybe this little tidbit of info might help someone someday.  The specifics of my issue was that I was trying to use `build(described_class)` to build instances from factories in my `RSpec` specs and this works just fine with un-namespaced classes but not with classes inside modules.  The reason is that internally when looking up factories FactoryGirl will use `ActiveSupport`'s `underscore` helper to normalise the factory name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the actual class, rather than a string with the class name:

```
Factory.define :client1_ad, :class => Client1::Ad do |ad|
```

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work. I get 'undefined method `is' for #<Class:0xbea9024> (NoMethodError)'.I've also tried:  
`Factory.define Client1::Ad do |ad|