# Defining factories for a class inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, factory-bot

I am pretty new to factory_girl and I have the following problem.

I have a class say of the form:

```
class Fruit::Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Suppose I need to create factories for this class. How should I do it? In other words is there a set_fixture_class equivalent for factories?

My apple_factory.rb is as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do |f|
  factory 'apple' do
    variety : washington
  end
end
```

I have all the required gems and my folder structure is of the form `test/factory/apple_factory.rb`. When I execute my tests I get `uninitialized constant Apple`. Where do I set the class definition? Do I need to set a factory helper?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like you are using namespaces for your models.

Take a look at this question and answer:
[Using factory_girl_rails with Rspec on namespaced models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349378/using-factory-girl-rails-with-rspec-on-namespaced-models)

```
Factory.define :apple, :class => Fruit::Apple do |f|
  f.variety 'Fuji'
end
```