# FactoryGirl factory for namespaced class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Any links to documentation proving or disproving my thoughts here would be very appreciated; I can't seem to find any.

AFAIK, if you had a Rails application with a `Product` model, you could define a FactoryGirl factory as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    # stuffs
  end
end
```

and then call your factory in tests with (RSpec example)

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
```

but you may *also* call it with

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(Product) }
```

This is helpful if you're wanting to keep your model tests a bit more dynamic and free to change with RSpec's `described_class` helper.

**My problem:**

I've got a model that happens to be namespaced

```
class Namespace::MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # model stuffs
end
```

with a factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_model, class: Namespace::MyModel do
    # factory stuffs
  end
end
```

and when attempting to use RSpec's helpers...

```
RSpec.describe Namespace::MyModel do
  let(:my_object) { FactoryGirl.create(described_class) }
  # testing stuffs
end
```

FactoryGirl complains of a missing factory

```
Factory not registered: Namespace::MyModel
```

Am I missing this feature of FactoryGirl, without understanding its true purpose? Or is there another way I can define my factory to resolve correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using factory\_girl\_rails with Rspec on namespaced models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349378/using-factory-girl-rails-with-rspec-on-namespaced-models)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I know how to set up the factory and use it as documented by FactoryGirl. My question pertains to how FactoryGirl resolves classnames to factory names.

Comment: For anyone who may be curious, I've also opened up an issue on FactoryGirl's GitHub page to try and get the opinions of the development team on this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/740

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try

```
RSpec.describe Namespace::MyModel do
  let(:my_object) { FactoryGirl.create(:my_factory) }
  # testing stuffs
end
```

FactoryGirl is usually used by factory name, but not class name, that is defines.

You can have a multiple factories, that define instances of the same class. The difference between them can be in fields values, for example.

Or you can dynamicly get factory name, from described_class name.
It is already answered at [How do you find the namespace/module name programmatically in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133357/how-do-you-find-the-namespace-module-name-programatically-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Using the factory as you describes works fine. I've been doing that. What I'm curious of is whether I can pass a namespaced class name to FactoryGirl and have it resolve to a factory that is defined on that class.